# Не могу понять как решить задачу в javascript

Tags: javascript

В книге Моргана Ника имеется задача в конце главы об объектах.

Как её реализовать? Создать цикл или...

Я буквально дней 20 как изучаю программирование.

Мой кусок кода:

```
var scores = {
    player1: 10,
    player2: 5,
    player3: 15
};
```

Текст самой задачи:

> ## 1. Подсчет очков
>
> Представьте, что вы играете в какую-нибудь игру со своими друзьями и вам нужно вести счет. Создайте для этого объект и назовите его scores.
>   Пусть ключами будут имена ваших друзей, а значениями — набранные ими очки (0 или больше).
>   Счет игроков надо будет увеличивать по мере того, как они зарабатывают новые очки. 
>   Как вы будете менять счет игрока, хранящийся в объекте scores?

P.S. Поправьте меня, если я где-то сделал ошибку.

Comment: О чем вопрос? `scores.palyer1++;`

Comment: @Арслан Муразиков, а что если будет миллион или больше? Тогда как будете действовать?

Comment: @And, будет миллион чего?

Comment: @Grundy наверно говорит о том что если будет миллион или больше очков.

Comment: @And навреное если в цикле указать ограничитель в виде:
while (count<=500)

Comment: @Grundy, пожалуйста, прочитайте вопрос (там сказано увеличивать игроков, да и вообще у игроков также может быть, что-то) я к тому. что прописывать миллион записей и опций в ручную не есть гуд. Для этого нужно делать динамику, которая будет помогать в создании и хранении необходимой информации.

Comment: @And, _**Счет игроков** надо будет увеличивать по мере того, как они зарабатывают новые очки_ - я может куда-то не туда смотрю?

Comment: @Grundy, копни чуток глубже, зачем начинать с бесполезного? Чем будет хороша такая игра?

Comment: @And, куда еще глубже? _Чем будет хороша такая игра?_ - что значит чем? Это обычная игра с постоянным количеством игроков.

Comment: @And, добавит пару методов добавления и удаления игрока, вот и вся динамика

Comment: @And, и хотелось бы увидеть место откуда ты взял _там сказано увеличивать игроков_

Comment: @Grundy, счет игроков. Я ошибся. Ну все равно, вот и другая задачка =)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Объясняю как: 
1) Организовать бесконечный цикл 
2) Выбрать случайное слово из массива, который должен быть создан заранее.
3) Принимать введённые буквы от трёх игроков ( сперва попробовать от одного)
4) Изменить букву, которую ввёл **player** в слове.

Некий итог типа: if (slovo.indexOf("vvedennayaBukva")!=1)score +=10;
else score -=10;
вообще мне кажется эту задачку можно реализовать по разному. Всем спасибо за внимание